# Tortoise revert changes from this revision

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have done a series of commits Commit 1,Commit 2,Commit 3,Commit 4.
I dont want to take commit 2 for my document.
So for my document commits to be taken is  Commit 1,Commit 3,Commit 4.
Can i use revert changes from this revision on clicking of commit 2 to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the way you should go. `revert changes from this revision` is the right choise.
If you have done `revert changes ...` you have to do a new commit (kind of "anti"-commit" to Commit 2) to bring changes to repository.

Comment: @user3440907: If answer is helpful for you it would be nice if can upvote and/or accept the answer. Tanks.